# how can I solve error 'The handle is invalid' in serilog

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I have an Asp.net core web api using .net core 6.
I use Serilog to store the app log in a text file.
sometimes I get this error:

```
Caught exception while emitting to sink Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.ConsoleSink: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.
   at System.ConsolePal.WindowsConsoleStream.Write(ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(String value)
   at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.Write(String value)
   at Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.ConsoleSink.Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
   at Serilog.Core.Sinks.SafeAggregateSink.Emit(LogEvent logEvent)
```

could you please help me how can I solve this issue?

this is my appsetting:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "AppLogs/bckLog-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext"
    ]
  }
```

and this is my program.cs

```
  Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(message => { Log.Logger?.Error(message); Console.WriteLine(message); });
  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration).CreateLogger();
  builder.Host.UseSerilog();
```

Comment: I'd argue that's not a Serilog question - it's a hosting question: if the environment can't provide a consistently available console egress, the console sink certainly isn't going to a) buffer things (the File sink arguably should/does support retries, but that does not make sense for a Console sink) or b) stop the app (that's against the fundamental rules of Serilog - only the Audit mechanism provides semantics for waiting for and/or requiring writes to succeed). How/where are you hosting? Perhaps there's another sink that might be more appropriate?

Comment: Hm I jumped to conclusions based on the stack trace mentioning Console early on. Suggest you add detail of your actual Sink/Sinks config and your hosting arrangements so someone can more completely answer as to what makes sense in your context (the above is written as if you where using ONLY the console sink, and whatever your hosting was redirecting that to was periidically acting unstable).

Comment: @ruben-bartelink this is my app-setting : "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "AppLogs/bckLog-.log",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Console"
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext"
    ]
  }

Comment: @ruben-bartelink  and this is the program.cs:
  
  Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(message => { Log.Logger?.Error(message); Console.WriteLine(message); });
  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration).CreateLogger();
  builder.Host.UseSerilog();

Comment: suggest to edit that into the question, properly formatted. I personally don't know the answer as I've never encountered the situation, nor have I read the File sink impl or tests in recent times. Would suggest to go read in that repo to understand the retry/fail semantics at play when the File sink cannot write; it might also help you enhance the question further.